# android detail of intalled application

Tags: android, installed-applications

is there a way to get details about applications installed in the device?
I want to implement an app which can have at least names of installed applications.
thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to use PackageManager

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
final List appsList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
```